# Given a list of elements in lexicographical order (i.e. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), find the nth permutation - Average time to solve?

Tags: python, list, recursion, combinations

I stumbled across this interview question:

> Given a list of elements in lexicographical order (i.e. ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']), find the nth permutation

I tried it myself, and it took me about ~30 minutes to solve. (I ended up with a ~8-9 line solution in Python). Just curious -- how long "should" it take to solve this type of problem? Am I taking too long?

Comment: Here c# version (just FYI): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799696/how-to-find-permutation-of-a-given-string-with-its-rank/25082541#25082541

Answer (score 12):

9 min, including test

```
import math

def nthperm(li, n):
    n -= 1
    s = len(li)
    res = []
    if math.factorial(s) <= n:
        return None
    for x in range(s-1,-1,-1):
        f = math.factorial(x)
        d = n / f
        n -= d * f
        res.append(li[d])
        del(li[d])
    return res

#now that's fast...
nthperm(range(40), 123456789012345678901234567890)
```

Comment: it starts from 1 (first permutation), that's why the `n -= 1` and `<=`. btw you mean `math.factorial(len(li))`, right?

Comment: can you explain the part inside the loop?  d = n/f  n-= d*f

Comment: if you have a list like [1,2,3,4] then for the last 3 elements there are 3! permutations, if n<=3! the first element is going to be 1, if 3!<n<=2*3! the 2 and so on. once you got the first element substract the number of permutations you used up for that element, remove it from the list and start again..

Comment: I hoped someone will point out that destroying the original list is probably a bad idea, but oh well..

Comment: Yes, I was also concerned that the original list is being destroyed. I guess rather than doing del(li[d]) you can use array splicing to make a new list..

Comment: doing `li=list(li)` at start is probably easier

Comment: Agreed on the timing.  Recently ran into a variant of this question here: http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=24

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is interested in a solution that can find the "i-th" permutation when you look at the "r-length-permutations" (as represented by the `r` argument of [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)):

```
from math import factorial

def ith_permutation(i, seq, r=None):
    li = list(seq)
    length = len(li)

    if r is None:
        r = length
    res = []
    current_factorial = factorial(length) // factorial(length - r)

    if current_factorial <= i:
        raise ValueError('out of range')

    for x in range(length, length-r, -1):
        current_factorial //= x
        div, mod = divmod(i, current_factorial)
        i = mod
        res.append(li[div])
        del(li[div])

    return res
```

For example:

```
>>> ith_permutationutation(10, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
[2, 3]

>>> # correctness check:
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> list(permutations([0, 1, 2, 3, 4], 2))[10]
(2, 3)
```

Including a more complete test:

```
s = range(8)
for n in range(len(s)):
    for idx, item in enumerate(permutations(s, n)):
        assert list(item) == ith_permutation(idx, s, n)
```

Some parts of Karoly Horvath's answer were used here.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am missing something, I thought we can find it easily with [nth from itertools Recipes](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes) and [permutations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations, islice
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
def main():
    data = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    n = 7  # 0 indexed
    print nth(permutations(data), n)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: it's extremely slow if n is large, you have to generate n permutations and only 1 of them is going to be used. originatlly there was a post exactly like this but then the OP explained that the task is to do it without itertools help, and then the poster deleted it. leave it here, it's a perfectly fine solution for small n-s.