# randomly splitting a data set into training and test using java

Tags: java

I want to split my dataset randomly into training and testing data for naive Bayes classification in java. I know, I have one option to use weka but I don't want to use external libraries. what other possibilities do I have using java?

Comment: You can define your own randomization in java?  Do they need to be split evenly?  or do you want majority training and a subset to use for testing?

Comment: I have a constraint to keep 75% as training and 25% as test data, other than this no constraint.

Comment: I don't see where you have a problem doing so. Sounds easy, you may elaborate where exactly you have difficulties implementing this on your own. Show us what you have tried so far. I mean your question at its current state is broad. From your whole data, randomly choose 75% of the entries for the training set and use the rest as test data.

Comment: You need to do your research yourself. See [help/on-topic], third point...

Answer (score 1):

you could [randomly permute the indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946789/generating-random-permutation-uniformly-in-java), and then copy the first 75% of the indexed elements into a new array.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have solved my problem and split the data into training(75%) and test set. and later randomised the data using swap.

code for randomising the data:

```
        private static void shuffleArray(ArrayList<Record> records) {

     int n = records.size();
     Random random = new Random();
     random.nextInt();
     for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
         int change = i + random.nextInt(n - i);
         swap(records, i, change);
     }
}

private static void swap(ArrayList<Record> records, int i, int change) {

     Record helper = records.get(i);
     records.set(i, records.get(change)) ;
     records.set(change, helper);

}
```