# Call specific permutation using a number index

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I'm using the `itertools.permutations` function to create a list of all combinations of characters in a list, then joining the results together, like this:

```
from itertools import permutations

def iterate(it):
    for x in it:
        print("".join(list(x)))

k_c = "1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM. "

iterate(permutations(list(k_c),10))
```

This is what it produces:

```
>>>1234567890
   123456789q
   123456789w
   123456789e
   123456789r
   123456789t
   123456789y
   123456789u
   123456789i
   123456789o
   ...
```

The problem that I have is this; I need to create strings like this that are 100 characters long, such as: `1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDJ1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDJ` and the program will stall, as it takes too long t run`iterate(permutations(list(k_c),100))` I was wondering if it would be possible for the program to just return a specific string, like this:

```
permutation_string(k_c,100,87)
>>> 1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDJ1234567890qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnmQWERTYUIOPASDJ
```

And it would return the 87th value within the list.
I realise this seems like a strange question, but any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you have permutations of length larger than the sequence length?

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, it does allow that

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the ith permutation of a given string/list then this answer will work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46132585/8189212