# Generate one permutation from an index

Tags: algorithm, permutation

Is there an efficient algorithm to generate a permutation from one index provided? The permutations do not need to have any specific ordering and it just needs to return every permutation once per every possible index. The set I wish to permute is all integers from 0~255.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, in your case, the permutations coincide with the indices themselves. Why not return the index?

Comment: Note that log2(256!) = 1684 bits (around) = 210.5 bytes. So, the index would be about as long as the permutation array itsel (256 bytes).

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are looking for with sample input and output? Currently, it is very unclear.

Comment: Related: [Finding n-th permutation without computing others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7918806/finding-n-th-permutation-without-computing-others); [Given a list of elements in lexicographical order (i.e. ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')), find the nth permutation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6784148/given-a-list-of-elements-in-lexicographical-order-i-e-a-b-c-d-f/6784359#6784359)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, the problem is as follows: You are given two integers `n` and `k`, and you want to find the `k`th permutation of `n` integers. You don't care about it being the `k`th lexicographical permutation, but it's just easier to be lexicographical so let's stick with that.

This is not too bad to compute. The base permutation is `1,2,3,4...n`. This is the `k=0` case. Consider what happens if you were to swap the 1 and 2: by moving the 1, you are passing up every single permutation where 1 goes first, and there are `(n-1)!` of those (since you could have permuted `2,3,4..n` if you fixed the `1` in place). Thus, the algorithm is as follows:

```
for i from 1 to n:
    j = k / (n-i)! // integer division, so rounded down
    k -= j * (n-i)!
    place down the jth unplaced number
```

This will iteratively produce the kth lexicographical permutation, since it repeatedly solves a sub-problem with a smaller set of numbers to place, and decrementing k along the way.

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation in python in module [more-itertools](https://pypi.org/project/more-itertools/): [nth_permutation](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/more.html#nth_permutation).

Here is an implementation, adapted from the code of more_itertools.nth_permutation:

```py
from sympy import factorial

def nth_permutation(iterable, index):
    pool = list(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    c = factorial(n)
    index = index % c
    result = [0] * n
    q = index
    for d in range(1, n + 1):
        q, i = divmod(q, d)
        if 0 <= n - d < n:
            result[n - d] = i
        if q == 0:
            break
    return tuple(map(pool.pop, result))

print( nth_permutation(range(6), 360) )
# (3, 0, 1, 2, 4, 5)
```

Comment: @KellyBundy I deleted it because the OP actually rearranged the data in a different way than what I thought. I thought they were grouping the elements so that all duplicates are close together. But actually they're putting one occurrence of every element first, then grouping the remaining duplicates. I guess we could do `uniques = set(l); return list(chain(uniques, (Counter(l) - Counter(uniques)).elements())` but I'm not sure how helpful that would be to the OP.

Comment: Yes, I find that difficulty of communication frustrating too. I guess it's not so surprising that using `set` adds overhead?

Comment: The set takes some time, yes, but the biggest part appears to be the Counter subtraction: [benchmark of parts](https://ideone.com/Roqg9q). I've put a chat room link on my profile now, maybe that helps, and maybe if enough people do that, SO will offer a standardized lightweight functionality :-)